# How to extract $ symbol from environment variable?

Tags: arrays, perl, environment-variables

I have a text file with lines such as,

```
$ENVGEN/path/to/file
```

The `ENVGEN` refers to an environment variable and I need to re-evaluate this line using the actual value of `ENVGEN` in my environment settings.

I could separate the `$ENVGEN` string out to a standalone element of an array, but I still need to evaluate it and re-form the path.

Comment: provide sample data to work with.

Comment: What do you mean by _stored as one element of array_?

Comment: What are you doing other than just accessing `$ENV['ENVGEN']`?

Comment: $ENVGEN is stored into array. So, if we go by word, then how can I extract $ symbol from $ENVGEN and then i put into $ENV{'ENVGEN'} and I can get value.

Comment: I have one file. In this file directory path is given. Like
$ENVGEN/xyc/yha/
So, How can I get full path of directory?

Comment: And how this file and path relate to the ENVGEN env variable?

Comment: $ENVGEN is 0th, xyc is 1st and yha is 2nd element of array.

Comment: I want value of $ENVGEN, so that I an access that full path and so i can open that directory.

Comment: Assuming your array is, `@myarray = ("abc", "def");` you can get the value of the first element as `$myarray[0]`

Comment: That I know, but How can i get value of $ENVGEN from that array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl keeps environment variables in a special hash named %ENV, it isn't an array. You can retrieve it with `$ENV{'ENVGEN'}`.

For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
print "PATH=".$ENV{'PATH'}."\n";
print "ENVGEN=".$ENV{'ENVGEN'};
```

**EDIT**. Replacing a reference to env variable with its value,

```
# say we read a line from a file, and we got this:
my $line_from_file = '$ENVGEN/path/to/file';

# split the path to components
my @path_components = split('/', $line_from_file);

# the first component is known to refer to an env variable,
# replace it with its value, chopping the '$' character from
# the start of the variable description
$path_components[0] = $ENV{substr($path_components[0], 1)};

# join the components back to form the re-evaluated path
$path_to_file = join('/', @path_components);
```

Comment: I have one file. In this file directory path is given. Like $ENVGEN/xyc/yha/. $ENVGEN is env variable. So, How can I get full path of directory?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case,

```
s/\$([A-Z_a-z][A-Z_a-z0-9]*)/ $ENV{$1} || "\$$1" /gex;
```

will substitute apparent environment variables with their value, and (appear to) leave them untouched if they are not defined in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/~nobull/String-Interpolate-0.3/lib/String/Interpolate.pm) for this.

```
# FOO = $BAR/to/file
# BAR = /path

use String::Interpolate;
my $foo = String::Interpolate::interpolate($ENV{'FOO'}, \%ENV);
print "$foo\n"; # /path/to/file
```